# Having 2x onClick within the same tag

Tags: javascript, onclick

This might have something to do with 'event bubbling' but how can I have 2 onClick events (1 to expand img and 1 to return to original size) within the same tag?

e.g

```
<img class="a1" width="140" height="140" onClick="this.width=420;this.height=560;" onClick="this.width=140;this.height=140;" />
```

As it is now the second onClick doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want it to alternate between the two sizes? If so, you should write a _single_ function which performs the switch, ideally [not using DOM0 attributes at all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

*Not javascript, but you'll get the idea*

```
onclick(){
    isClicked ^= true

    if(isClicked){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two equal attributes to the same tag, but you can do what you want this way (not tested... =D ):

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var img = document.getElementById("your_img");
  img.onclick = function(){
    var size = this.getAttribute("data-size");
    if(size === "big"){
      this.style.width = "140px";
      this.style.height = "140px";
      this.setAttribute("data-size", "small");
    } else {
      this.style.width = "560px";
      this.style.height = "420px";
      this.setAttribute("data-size", "big");
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="your_img" src="anything.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
#your_img{
  height:140px;
  width:140px;
}
```